# ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED

Tags: 12.04, lts

When I start the ADV Android emulator I get the following error:

```
ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
       you will have to do at least one of the following:
       - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
       - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
       Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
       aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
       Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.
```

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and run

```
sudo android avd -force-32bit
```

That should start it in 32bit mode

The 32bit version of adv is no longer supported, a 64bit OS is highly recommended for this due to 32bit memory limitations, there may be complications.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux Android emulator binaries require a computer with a sufficient amount of RAM to run properly, which is normally a 64-bit architecture computer with enough RAM to be suitable for installing a 64-bit operating system on it.

Android itself is also moving towards a x64 architecture, so by staying with 32-bit you will get left behind eventually.

If you got the error message in your question when using the ADT (Android Developer Tools) plugin for Eclipse, you should also consider this. If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) to receive all the latest IDE updates. The Android Virtual Device Manager (AVD Manager) is included in Android Studio. For help moving projects, see [Migrating to Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html). You can install Android Studio in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu by adding the [Android Studio for Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paolorotolo/+archive/ubuntu/android-studio) to your software sources.